# Can't get data from web api in Angular

Tags: angular

In My Angular app I have an service which gets data from a web api, the url address is as follows:

```
/api/user/1
```

So the number prefix is what user it is. My service is written so I can get the `activeUser` and bind that information into another view. But no data seems to be coming through? So my code is:

**service.ts**

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  public users: any = null;
  public activeUser = null;

  public getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.users) {
      return of(this.users);
    } else {
      return this.http.get<any>('/api/user').pipe(
        tap(users => {
          this.users = users;
        })
      );
    }
  }

  public getUser(id): Observable<any> {
    const existingUser = this.users ? this.users.results.find(user => user.id === id) : null;
    if (existingUser && existingUser.addresses) {
      return of (existingUser);
    } else {
      return this.http.get<any>(`/api/user/${id}`).pipe(
        tap(user => {
          if (existingUser) {
            existingUser.address = user.address;
          }
        })
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**App component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private elementRef : ElementRef
  ) {
  }
  public customer_id;
  public user_id;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customer_id = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('activeCustomer');
    this.user_id = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('activeUser');
  }
}
```

**Then the view.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Request } from '../../models/request.model'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppComponent } from '../../../app.component';
import { nowService } from '../../services/servicenow.service';
import { UserService } from '../../../shared/services/user.service';

import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

  private customer_id = this.appComponent.customer_id;

  private user_id = this.appComponent.user_id;
```

**Html:**

```html
<p class="text-small text-gray mb-5">{{user_id}}</p>
```

All this but no joy...

Comment: Your question seems incomplete, where are you calling `getUsers()`?

Comment: Any error logs?

Comment: No errors in the log

Comment: I am not sure with that `tap()` there. Shouldn't there be `subscribe()`?

Comment: the "view.ts" looks broken/incomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.http.get()` needs full end point of API i.e including `http://localhost:4412/api/user/` for local API.